# Encrypting and decrypting zip archive via openssl in php

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, cryptography, php-ziparchive

I am having some troubles with decrypting zip archive via openssl in php.

Thats how i encrypt it with my public key.

```
public function encrypt($data) {
        openssl_public_encrypt($data, $encrypted, $this->pubKey);

        return chunk_split(base64_encode($encrypted));
    }
```

Encryption output looks like this:

> T5Nu3gGqCnwFhBoctx0D1bOvrBg9VfKNJaVz5RSu4OBsKI2qBdw1sZ4YQNC8ya3xU/tvpcTtw/vd
>   LKZeKaFZloPP49hu9uRX7+rJYegVHHLKBdP0JX380mmJCq+4kj1R3gt4l4zzBGuvEZMQnSffOgdR
>   hdao0DcSU0R2feOKkyuIy9NVxtmX9iXVGmOalyy0s4azk9mD5KnHcKIYgJG7YCyAr97lX6A7MKMi
>   xq9/hpvLhdQa5cZH6f1eXoIFx9uRSIaKdeKmZzHPVUPOVnqlHQuhtUE+Of/RnWYYKoS280TUROKV
>   fk7jepF+w3wxQ1yrYLDPyglWBCjyaHQbdDTB7w==

Then  I am trying to decrypt my zip archive back.

```
public function decrypt($data) {
        openssl_private_decrypt(base64_decode($data), $out, $this->prvKey);

        return $out;
    }
```

I am just getting path of zip archive, something like

```
C:\OpenServer\domains\project\src\AppBundle\Command/../../../backup/2016_04_05_full.zip
```

How should i decrypt encrypted zip archive file?

thanks!

Comment: openssl_public_encrypt encrypts the supplied $data, in this case it is the zip file path. To encrypt an entire file requires a bit more work.  Here's a place to start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30742390/encrypting-large-files-in-php-with-openssl

Comment: @dbugger That shows just the symmetric encryption part though. You'd need to generate a random data key and encrypt that with the public key using the function above (i.e. create a hybrid cryptosystem).